# Cocos2D V3 Blur effect performance test without iOS device

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, graphic-effects

I am testing the blur effect (`CCEffectBlur`) in Cocos 2D V3 and I found that when I add an effect to an `EffectNode` it takes up to 5 seconds to appear in the IOS Simulator screen. (I know that the IOS Simulator is not to test performance)

When I run the same code in my device (iPhone 6), it appears almost instant.

My problem is to test the performance in old devices like iPhone 4S or iPhone 5 but, unfortunately, I don't have those devices to do some tests.

Is there any way to check my game's performance on those devices without the devices?

This is what I am testing.

- I have a hierarchy with an `EffectNode` as a root node.
- I am using a code like the following to add the effect
  `effectNode.effect = [CCEffectBlur effectWithBlurRadius:10];`

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, the iOS simulator is not for testing performance, so unfortunately there is no way of testing you app at a lower performance level.

I would recommend finding an iPhone 4S/5 on eBay ($140 and $200 respectively) or finding a friend with one of these phones. (or just make sure that your app can achieve very high performance on your iPhone 6 and hope it will run on a 4S (5-10x less powerful))

'Very high performance' here depends on what you are testing. Since you want to test the Blur effect (ie: graphical) performance, all you can do is ensure you have a very high FPS or very low delay between graphical updates.

Keep your app to less than 512MB of RAM (or less, the 4S only has 512 and some might be used by the system/other apps), and grab a good system load app from the store and make sure your app only uses a small fraction of resources. Take a look at some [benchmarks](http://www.ubergizmo.com/products/lang/en_us/devices/iphone-4s,iphone-6/) and comparisons to compare performance.

Comment: About the 2 first options, I know both but I am looking for some kind of simulator to run in the computer.  About the part 'very high performance on your iPhone 6', it is too difficult to measure.  What would be very high performance?

Comment: 'Very high performance' depends on what you are testing. Since you want to test the Blur effect (ie: graphical) performance make sure you have a very high FPS. Keep your app to less than 512MB of RAM (or less, the 4S only has 512 and some might be used by the system/other apps), and grab a good system load app from the store and make sure your app only uses a small fraction of resources.

Comment: @CrApHeR (I would also add an option to disable or reduce the blur effect, or an option to replace it with darkening the screen (or something) )